# How to extract numbers of a string unix

Tags: bash, unix

Hello and happy new year. I have a question;i have a file named shipsIMO.txt in unix which contains the imo code of ships like:

```
IMO84855
IMO58484
```

How can I have as an output only the numbers using a bash script?
Am I close?

```
echo "shipsIMO.txt"|tr -cd [:digit:]>single.txt
```

Comment: `echo "shipsIMO.txt"` should be `cat "shipsIMO.txt"` - but it'd remove whitespaces (including newlines) too. Is that what you want? If you want to keep them: `tr -cd '[[:space:][:digit:]]' < shipsIMO.txt > single.txt` should do

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description, no images, no links) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Thank you so much that was what i wanted!

Answer (score 3):

> How can I have as an output only the numbers

In that case, you are very close. `echo "shipsIMO.txt"` will not print the content of the file. It'll literally print `shipsIMO.txt`. To print the content of the file, use `cat`:

```
cat shipsIMO.txt | tr -cd '[:digit:]' > single.txt
```

or without `cat`, making `tr` read directly from the file:

```
tr -cd '[:digit:]' < shipsIMO.txt > single.txt
```

Both versions above would create `single.txt` with the content (no spaces or newlines):

```
8485584855
```

If you want to ...

```
# keep whitespaces (including newlines) and digits:
tr -cd '[:space:][:digit:]' < shipsIMO.txt > single.txt

# keep only newlines and digits:
tr -cd '\n[:digit:]' < shipsIMO.txt > single.txt
```

Both would produce `single.txt` with this content:

```
84855
84855
```

Comment: Fan fact: `[` `]` are parsed literally by `tr` in `[[` `]]`. It's just `[:stuff:]`, not `[[:stuff:]]`. Just `tr -cd '[:space:][:digit:]'` and just `tr -cd '\n[:digit:]'`. Compare `tr -cd '[[:space:][:digit:]]' <<<'['` vs `tr -cd '[:space:][:digit:]' <<<'['`

Comment: @KamilCuk Oups... Thanks for spotting that error. Fixed!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily with `sed`, removing all non-numeric characters:

```
sed -e 's/[^0-9]//g' shipsIMO.txt
```

Comment: With the global flag you do not need the `*`, simple `sed -e 's/[^0-9]//g' shipsIMO.txt`.

Comment: good point - I could also omit `-e` in this case, but I tend to leave it in since it avoids issues if more scripts are added later.

Comment: For a single editing _command_ `-e` is not required and is used when multiple editing _commands_ are used with the same occurrence of `sed`.  So indeed `sed 's/[^0-9]//g' shipsIMO.txt` is valid and all that's needed in this use case.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with sed to remove all `IMO` string, it will work with space and line break:

```sh
sed 's/IMO//g'  shipsIMO.txt > single.txt
```